# Assigning ID to all elements of a page in angular automatically

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

We are working on an enterprise web application, at the moment we hired an e2e test engineer to perform automation tests.

He asked us to assign IDs to every single element in pages.
Is there a tool or something to perform this action automatically and adds some random IDs to all elements in HTML files ?
we already have a bunch of files and it would take much time to add them manually.

According to the following question,  A selector like `body div:nth-of-type(4) ul li:nth-child(5) a` to check a certain link is not only obviously ugly, but also prone to changes in the markup. A small change could break half of your testsuite.
[Adding ID attribute to all HTML elements of a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153986/adding-id-attribute-to-all-html-elements-of-a-web-application)

We are using: Angular v6 / Material v2 / Protractor / Jasmine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have been working on a React project for which we are doing e2e testing using 'Mocha-Nightwatch'. As a UI automation tester I needed something to access the elements, there were following options for me:

1) Using the "***CSS selector***", which is ugly and long as you mentioned.

2) Using The "***X-path***" of the element, which is again long and much more confusing

3) The best of all the "***Id's***" for elements [because they are unique throughout the app]. But the problem was when we gave id an element, React web pack will append a alphas numeric string to the id each time you build the application,making a unique id every time. So again id's failed in this scenerio.

4) The thing which we settled for was "***Classes***" for the elements which we wanted to access in testing.

As far is going the id or classnames is concerned, there is **no** shortcut in doing it. You need to give meaningful names for the id/classnames, some tool [which may or may not exist] will add some random id to all the elements which is not at all needed, and just increases the space complexity of your application.

The better solution is take up module by module and add class or id's[id they are not made dynamic by Webpack in you case] names by yourself.

The approach we used was we taught the automation tested how to add class names or id's, and how to inspect in the chrome dev tools, if the id's/classes really exist or not. But the limitaion of this is, the tester may add some classes or id which may conflict with your functionality. to solve this you can use a proper naming convention, for e.g. we use .test-something-something or #test-something-somethig as our convention for naming the test id's and classes.

Here is a sample from your selectors file:

```
  usernameInput: '.test--auth-username > input',
  passwordInput: '.test--auth-password > input',
  loginButton: '.test--auth-submit > button',
  loginError: '.test--auth-error',
  inputError: '.test--inputField-errorText',
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive answer.
so I concluded that the best way is to write a clean and organized code with classes and IDs.
Your tip about having a special naming convention for the test id's and classes was great for us since we always had such concern about conflicts in names between front-end developers and automation testers.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor comment, it might be smart to use data-test-id (a custom data element) in favor of using the "regular" html5 ID. this allows you to benefit from plugins like: https://github.com/mukeshsoni/babel-plugin-remove-data-test-id-attribute, which in turn cleans up your production output.

I am not aware of any libraries that automatically assign test-ids to your  elements (and most probably you want to be in control of where the test ID is added in the first place)

Comment: Material components don't let you add custom attributes to them. The solution for that AFAIK is to turn off 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA', but that has its set-backs. How do you add custom attributes to such components?

Comment: And here is how you can do it: ```[attr.test-id]="your-custom-id```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend to assign id to each element on page. For automation we can use `CSS Selector` and `XPath` to locate element from page, finding element by ID is not the only way.

And if you choose to use automatical ID, you have to make sure the same element will always get the same ID when you build the app each time, otherwise the automation script have to change for each app build.

I will recommend to add ID to key element on the whole page, for example, we have one page and we divide the page into 4 areas:  head, left side bar, student table, footer.  We can only add ID on the container element of the 4 areas, so only 4 IDs we need to add, rather than all elements. And add `css class name` in `class` attribute on sub elements.

With above approach, automation script can use `findElement` chain as below:

```
// find the container element of area firstly
WebElement headArea = driver.findElement(<By.id('id of head area')>);

// find sub element within container element
headArea.findElement(<By.css('css selector of sub element')>);
```

Comment: What is the solution for your second paragraph? There is a solution to have elements always with the same ID every time the app builds?

Comment: I don't know how the automatical id generated for your app HTML page,  I guess it generated when build app by some plugin of build/package tool.  If there is such plugin used, you can look into the plugin to see any setting can make to always use same id on specific elements

Comment: Do you know any idea to generate automatically ids compatible with js? I mean, without passing manually with a loop through all elements of the HTML? To make them persistent, I think I can use a database or an hash function